# How do I scan a QR code from an image stored on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios

iOS 11 added the option to scan a QR code with the built-in camera app on an iPhone. However, I couldn’t find an option to scan a QR code from an image saved to my camera roll or otherwise already saved to Files and not something printed or physical external to the phone.

How can I scan a QR code from an image already saved on an iPhone?

Answer (score 6):

The app [QR Reader for iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/qr-reader-for-iphone/id368494609?mt=8) on the App Store is quite a powerful QR code app. Check it out.

I use it infrequently, but I'm glad I have it in my toolbox.

Another reader that isn't scammy or tries to advertise / monetize your use is [QRafter Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/qrafter-pro-qr-code-barcode/id468610525?mt=8) and it's very solid over years of use.

*Disclaimer:* We're satisfied users of QR Reader/ QRafter for iPhone, and there are no financial or other connections between to [TapMedia Ltd](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/developer/tapmedia-ltd/id359632753?mt=8) or QRafter.

Comment: Thanks, @bmike. How is it scummy and monetizes my use? I'm intrigued.

Comment: Both of these readers are awesome. Feel free to roll back or edit my edit if I’m somehow putting your suggestion in anything but top billing. Just wanted a second candidate app to try.

Comment: I see no problem with your edit or comment @bmike. I just tried QRafter on my iPhone and it is indeed awesome. We make QRafter available on our managed fleet of iPads at work, but I'd never used it myself.

Comment: I don’t see anything in either App Store listing that says it can read an internal image.

Comment: @WGroleau I’ve just tried QR Reader (the first app linked here) and it has a flower icon to import a QR code from a photo already in the photo library. Paired with the screenshot tool, this is a way to read a QR code from any app or website viewed on the same device.